# Why object is not inserted into firebase database when sendEmailVerification() method (method of Firebase Auth) is called?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to insert an object into firebase database when sendEmailVerification() method is called.

**Note** : I called sendEmailVerification() after creating new user account.

RegistrationModel is my Model class .

code of sendEmailVerification:

```
final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

user.sendEmailVerification()
   .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
         if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // email sent
                            String userId = savePref.getUid();
                            registrationModel = new RegistrationModel();
                            registrationModel.setStatus(ONLINE_STATUS);
                            registrationModel.setName("");
                            registrationModel.setPassword(passwordFromRegister);
                            registrationModel.setKey("");
                            registrationModel.setEmailId(user.getEmail());
                            registrationModel.setGenerated_links("");
                            registrationModel.setNO_OF_GENERATED_LINK(NO_OF_GENERATED_LINK);
                            registrationModel.setNO_OF_CHATING_PERMISSION(NO_OF_CHATING_PERMISSION);

                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("RegistrationModel")
                                    .child(userId).setValue(registrationModel);

                        }

                    }
                });
```

I search a lot but didn't find any solution for that !

**Note** I get this warning `setValue at /RegistrationModel/KxvrHcEQXdRnV45XqZecUDtUX8c2 failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied`

Comment: did you make sure that userId is filled?

Comment: Also, can we have a look at your RegistrationModel?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque Yea userId have some value , i already checked that !

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque when i called same logic out side of sendEmailVerification() method , everything work fine !

Comment: humm, so your model class should be fine then. I know it's a silly question, is the executing entering task.isSuccessful?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque Yea its executing ,i checked via debugging tool

Comment: gonna run your code, 1 sec

Comment: I've run a similar code and it is saving to the database, the problem is not with firebase. I'd suggest you to add a completion listener to the setValue method and check if it returns a DatabaseError

Comment: Check your logcat output for warning and errors from the database. For example: does the user have permissions on the location you're trying to write?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen okay wait i will once more !

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque and Frankvan I get this warning " setValue at /RegistrationModel/KxvrHcEQXdRnV45XqZecUDtUX8c2 failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied"

Comment: what are your database rules?

Comment: this->  {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}

Comment: did you make any changes to your app package name or anything like that? this can also be caused by an outdated google-services.json file

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque no ! and had you run the code?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque I re-download google-services.json file and run it but its showing same warning !

Comment: The `Task` completes when the email is sent, not when the user is verified. I wrote up a quick answer for that, although I'm not completely sure what causes the authentication state to drop.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [documentation for `sendEmailVerification`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#sendEmailVerification()) it says:

> ```
> public Task<Void> sendEmailVerification (ActionCodeSettings actionCodeSettings)
> ```
>
> Initiates email verification for the user. Takes in an ActionCodeSettings to allow linking back to your app in the email.
>
> **Returns a
> `Task` to track completion of the sending operation.**

To when the task completes the email has been sent. That doesn't mean that the user has clicked to verify their email address yet, nor that they are authenticated.

I'm not really sure where it happens, but it looks like your authentication state is being lost somewhere between:

```
final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
```

and

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("RegistrationModel")
                                .child(userId).setValue(registrationModel);
```

Comment: thank you so much for support ! so how can i achieve that , i have been searching from last 24 hours .

Comment: it worked when i use this rule -> {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth == null"
  }
}

Comment: but i am getting warning "setValue at /RegistrationModel/W41yOKmeSsUSYImak3Cgxh0llow1/status failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied" whenever i tried to setvalues on other places , what is the problem exactly?

Comment: With the rules you showed, the only way I can explain a "permission denied" is when you're not signed in when you perform that operation.